# Alternative Touchpad drivers

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I would like to change my Windows 7 touchpad drivers so that they work more like ubuntu's touchpad.

#### Ubuntu

For example in ubuntu you can move you 1 finger on the right side of the trackpad to scroll up and down.  Left click just requires you to click down anywhere on the trackpad and right click is 2 fingers down.

#### Windows7

Right now on my Samsung QX411 left click occurs on the left side of the touchpad.  Right click is on the right side of the touchpad and you use two fingers to scroll up and down.  The problem is that the scrolling is incredibly glitchy.  And the pad isn't sensitive enough to scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Synaptics supported mousepad, you can go under mouse settings to change the mouse operations to your heart desire.

Generally speaking it is actually quiet easy to get a similar operation if you just mess with the settings under

**Contoral Panel -> Ease Of Access -> Make the mouse easier to use -> Mouse Settings -> Device Settings**

There are interactive pictures that work incredibly well.